# Warnings when cropping SpatRaster or read/write NetCDF files using terra package

Tags: r, raster, spatial, gdal, terra

I am receiving two warning messages when using `terra` R packages on HPC. The same code works without warnings using Windows PC.

1. Cropping a SpatRaster object

```
require(dplyr)
require(terra)

# The projection of both extent and SpatRaster objects is `EPSG:4326`
CropExtent <- terra::ext(-26, 37.5, 34, 72)
Rstr <- terra::rast("PATH_To_MAP", raw = TRUE) %>%
    terra::crop(CropExtent) %>%

# Warning message:
# In x@cpp$crop(y@cpp, snap[1], extend[1], opt) :
#  GDAL Message 6: driver GTiff does not support open option so
```

2. Writing/reading a SpatRaster object (projected; `EPSG:3035`) into/from a NetCDF file.

```
# Saving NetCDF file
Map = terra::writeCDF(Rstr, filename = OutFileNC, overwrite = TRUE)
# loading NetCDF file
terra::rast("File.nc")
# Aslo when plotting the map
plot(Map)
```

```
# Warning messages:
# 1: In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :
# GDAL Message 1: dimension #1 (easting) is not a Longitude/X dimension. 
# 2: In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :
# GDAL Message 1: dimension #0 (northing) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
```

Should I care about these warnings? any explanation for them?

The installed versions on the HPC are:
gdal: 3.5.3
R: 4.3.2
terra: 1.7.71

Comment: Not sure if this will completely solve your issue, but note that your crop extent values are WGS84 (EPSG:4326). If you are using your CropExtent object to crop an object with an EPSG:3035 PCS, you're quite a few million metres away from home :) There also appears to be some missing code and warning text from your first codeblock.

Comment: For the first warning, the projection of the input map and the extent is EPSG:4326.

Comment: Check out [this issue](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1212). It appears that `terra` suppresses these warnings by default, but  in some cases if `sf` is loaded, the warnings will show. It could also be an issue with where `terra` looks for a valid timestamp. That link suggests the warnings can safely be ignored, but I cannot confirm definitively. At least it's a known issue.